# I cannot find a solution for botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError:

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am stuck trying to find a solution to the following error botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: invalid length for parameter Key, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf 
I am able to list, upload files to a static html page listing my S3 bucket/objects. But cannot download or delete without hitting the ParamValidationError.

I am using a text editor (nano) on EC2, Python2.7 Flask, flask-bootstrap.

I think I am missing a value in the brackets, but I haven't found a solution so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 @app.route('/download', methods=['POST'])
    def download():
    key = request.form['key']

    my_bucket = get_bucket()
    file_obj = my_bucket.Object(key).get() 

  File "/home/ec2-user/flask-s3-bucket/app.py", line 41, in download
    file_obj = my_bucket.Object(key).get()

ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid length for parameter Key, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf
```

Comment: What objects/types are being used as the key variable?  It looks like your key needs to be > 0.

Comment: looks like your key is an empty string

Comment: thanks for your comments I fixed the issue - I am nnow figuring out how a fixed it.

Comment: @mango1 It would be nice if you could add your solution as an answer. That way other users with the same issue can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

my_bucket.Object(key).get()

When calling the Object method it expects at least one value.
Check with the value of Key here. This must be getting generated as Null.Try replacing with hard coded value.